# Cross Browser: PHP Kill Sessions

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I'm attempting to kill a user's previous session before logging them in:  More context, I want to prevent users from signing in using the same username / password across different browsers or locations, stopping them from manipulating session state (like a balance of a game), across browsers.

Here's what I've done so far, but without success
1) Get the user's last session_id which is stored in the database as a user signs-in successfully, keeping that in a variable called $old_session_id

2) Attempt to delete the last session using the following code

```
session_id($old_session_id);
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

3) Attempt to start a new, clean, session for the user using session_start()

What I'm seeing is that the new session is not being started - user is logged out on both browesers

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

PHP sessions identified by a cookie set on the client's machine, and cookies are not shared between browsers. This is a non-issue.

Your code in #2 might explicitly change that user's session current session ID to that of the session in the previous browser *which would cause the problem you're attempting to solve*.

Also, you can only call session_start() *once per request* so of course #3 fails.

In short, just stop doing everything you've mentioned in your question and your problems will solve themselves.

Answer (score 0):

once the session is destroyed a new one has to be created.

If you only want to clear the values on the session you can also try this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array(); //unset all session variables
```

Answer (score 0):

sessions are stored in your browser only so if you so if you want to see if user is already logged in other browser you need to use database

add a row to your database with status 1 or 0

1 = "online";

0 = "offline";

in your login page check user status if 1

```
$query=mysql_query("select status from table_name were username=$_POST['username']");
$status=$query['status'];
if($status == 1)
{
redirect him to a page saying the account is already logged in
}else
{
let him in and update the database status = 1
}
```

while in logout page
 update the user status to 0 turning him offline

if you just want to delete all session use
use session start first before destroy then session start again cause you cant destroy a session without starting it

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_start();
```

but if you want to delete a specific session you need to use

```
unset($_SESSION['sessionname']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session_regenerate_id to create a new id.
Clear session data, regenerate id and start a new.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php